# Algebraic Geometry - seven points in a projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to find the Betti diagrams for each configuration, and I have difficulty for the case when there are some subsets of 3 collinear points but not 4 and for the case when the points are in general position.

For the first case I found two cubics that contain the line (one reducible and one irreducible) and I found one (I think reducible) cubic that doesn't contain the line. By a theorem I know that I need to have one more generator. I checked up to degree 6 but no luck. Any suggestions?

For the second case it is easy to see that there are 4 cubic generators, I think one reducible and two irreducible. Again by the same theorem I need one more generator, but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What is a Betti diagram?

Comment: Do you know what a resolution of an ideal? It has the form 
The Betti diagram is a table that tells us how many copies of generators of degree $i+j$ in the $i-$th free module, where $i$ i the raw and $j$ is the column in the Betti diagram